# How to get facebook verified login method (email or phone number)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am making this app where people can sign in with facebook. I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) from facebook. I was able to get a code for the user, send it to the sever, exchange it for an access token. now, I need to get the user email or phone number(whatever he used to sign into facebook).

I am doing a request like this using python requests library:

```
user_info_res = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', params={'fields': "id,first_name,last_name,email",'access_token': access_token})
```

Well, I am abel to get the email, which might be null if user signed in using phone number. What is the field for phone number that I should put there ?

Comment: You can't get the phone number.

Comment: Why ? If I can get the email, why can't I get the phone number ? I just need to know the user signing in method.

Comment: Look, I need to know that, because the user might be signed into two different providers(Google and facebook) using the same phone number or email. If he's signed into my app using one of them, I want to prevent him from signing in using the other provider. I want the phone number and email columns to be unique

Comment: That is impossible. There is no way to get the phone number. And even if the user signed up with email you may not get it because the user may not grant you permission to it.